# unable to use ASP.Net web service in cocoa application

Tags: cocoa

I am posting a xml to web service created in ASP.net using SOAP and it's not returning response returned by web service. It's returning following response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:ActionNotSupported</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The message with Action 'http://192.168.10.231/EBServiceHost/Service.svc' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).</faultstring>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Any Idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide more info about the service? Is it a WCF service your trying to call?

Comment: @Buzzer its too late to reply. I have resolved this issue. This was happening because I was sending wrong method. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because I was sending wrong method name. It was resolved by sending correct method name with request.

Comment: Did you read my answer?  - "I think another time we generated a proxy with svcutil with by default names soap actions with the fully qualified name of the class. So inspecting the wcf trace I found that the soapAction we were expecting = Namespace.Class.MethodName. However, the client (a java client sending soap 1.1 messages, was sending soapAction=MethodName." -

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this for a couple of different reasons.  One reason was because the was a binding mistmatch between the client and the server.  Specifically, we had an legacy client that was sending soap 1.1. messages to a wcf service that was configured with WSHttpBinding which is by default soap 1.2.  Once we changed on the binding on the server side things worked smoothly.  Also, as the error indicates make sure that your security mode and credentials are configured correctly.  I think another time we generated a proxy with svcutil with by default names soap actions with the fully qualified name of the class.  So inspecting the wcf trace I found that the soapAction we were expecting = Namespace.Class.MethodName.  However, the client (a java client sending soap 1.1 messages, was sending soapAction=MethodName.  We were able to solve that problem by simply replacing the fully qualified names from the generated proxy.

If you give me more details I may be able to figure out what your problem and solutions were so I can get this answer :)

Hope that helps!